# Radius units in GeoJSON item Circle

Tags: openlayers, geojson

There is a GeoJSON object:

```
  {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
      shape: "Circle",
      radius: 600000,
      name: "Unnamed Layer 1",
      category: "default",
    },
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [37.887051, 55.677584],
    },
    id: "bd256e54-98ba-4184-93a7-ff93e1562fa4",
  }
```

What is unit should be for radius? Now I use value radius: 600000. Perhaps in meters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v7.1.0/src/ol/geom/Circle.js#L217) in the source code, it is in the units of the projection.